# how to properly handle php undefined index

Tags: php, post

I have a script where a user can input some text, view it, and change it. It looks like that:

```
if(isset($_POST['change']))
{
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    echo"
    <form method='post' action='datei.php'>
    <p>You wrote: $text</p>
    <input name='text' type='hidden' size='21' value='$text'>
    <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Change'>
    </form>";
}else
{
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    echo"
    <form method='post' action='datei.php'>
    <p>Write some additional Information</p>
    <input name='text' type='text' size='21' value='$text'>
    <input name='change' type='submit' value='View'>
    </form>";
 }
```

When I load the page the first time, I get the following notification

```
Notice: Undefined index: text in ...
```

I found two solutions how to fix the problem:

1. Ignore Notifications
2. Use isset()

If I would use isset I would have to change two lines from above to:

```
 if(isset($_POST['text']))$text = $_POST['text'];
```

and

```
<input name='text' type='text' size='21' value='"; if(isset($_POST['text'])) echo $text; echo"'>
```

Since my original form has more then 20 input fields, this would make the code less readable and more likly for erros when editing the code. Is there any better way to get around the notification that I currently miss?

Comment: Times like this, I'd suggest separating your PHP and HTML by using a template engine

Comment: According to your html markup snippets, the field is called `information`, not `text`

Comment: When you get an `Undefined Index` error, **`print_r()` the array**. Then check if that index exists, whether the case is correct, whether there are any extra characters in the Index etc. If your form input is not even being passed over, then you might want to check your HTML markup, and ensure that it gets `POST`ed, by using Chrome Developer Tools (go to the Network tab, and click the submit button) or similar.

Comment: @Adam there's three places in your question, not just one, where you use information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First be sure that you define all the variables before using them, like

```
$text = false;
```

Plus, checking that a variable is set is always a good practice. Not to mention that you shouldn't be using $_POST directly.